# Не импортируется таблица стилей

Tags: html, css

Господа, не импортируется таблица стилей. Не могу понять почему.
Вот хтмл код

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        @import url ("style.css");

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Кошка
</body>
</html>
```

А вот содержимое самого файла style.css

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

Документ хтмл и файл стилей лежат в одной папке. Путь не содержит кириллицы. Что может быть ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так

```
@import"Путь до файла";
```

Answer (score 1):

По теме советую попробовать всё же прописать путь с указанием папки.

P.S. Как на счёт более привычного способа? Прописать в <head>...</head>

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Так то оно, конечно, работает, я не могу понять, почему оно не работает путем импорта.

Comment: Путь файла полностью пробовал прописывать? Несмотря на то, что в одной папке находятся.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку свою понял. @import url ("style.css"); Между url и ("style.css") не должно быть пробела